# ubuntu: how to add another file to PATH variable

Tags: ubuntu, path

I have a new file that I want to include in PATH variable. I know I can do it by using export command, but it will not stay for the new terminal that I'll open. I want that whenever I open a new terminal the new file will already be included in the $PATH variable.
What would you advice me to do?

Comment: You should ask this question at askubuntu.com and here is a post from there that will help you keep your Path variables intact: http://askubuntu.com/questions/275704/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables-path-and-m2-home-in-ubuntu-for-ma. You need to export an environment variable (/etc/somevariable)

Answer (score 1):

Add the path in your .bashrc file in the home directory. For example:

```
PATH="$PATH:/opt/sublime_text"
```

After that use the command

```
source .bashrc
```

and the exported path will be visible in any terminal.